# Create a table with the data read from XML file into word document using Open XML

Tags: c#, .net, xml, ms-word, openxml

I am trying to read the data from XML file and would like to generate the table in word document populated with the same  data. I am using below XML file and c# code to do the same.

I am using below code to create the table in word document

```
class DocumentCreation :IDisposable
{
    private MemoryStream _ms;
    private WordprocessingDocument _wordprocessingDocument;

    public DocumentCreation()
    {
        _ms = new MemoryStream();
        _wordprocessingDocument = WordprocessingDocument.Create(_ms, WordprocessingDocumentType.Document);
        var mainDocumentPart = _wordprocessingDocument.AddMainDocumentPart();
        Body body = new Body();
        mainDocumentPart.Document = new Document(body);
        ApplyHeader(_wordprocessingDocument);
        InsertTable(_wordprocessingDocument);
    }


    private void InsertTable(WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument)
    {
        string xmlFile = @"C:\wordDoc\movies.xml";   
        MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

        // How to read the XML and create a table in word document filled with data from XML
    }

    public static void ApplyHeader(WordprocessingDocument doc)
    {
        // Get the main document part.
        MainDocumentPart mainDocPart = doc.MainDocumentPart;

        HeaderPart headerPart1 = mainDocPart.AddNewPart<HeaderPart>("r97");
        .......
        ......
        ......
    }
    public void AddBulletList(List<Run> runList)
    {
        .......
        .......
     }
  }
```

below is where i am calling above class

```
   static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        string fileToCreate = @"C:\wordDoc\test.docx";

        if (File.Exists(fileToCreate))
            File.Delete(fileToCreate);

        var writer = new DocumentCreation();
        List<string> fruitList = new List<string>() { "This is bulleted point 1", "This is bulleted point 2", "This is bulleted point 3" };

        writer.AddBulletList(fruitList);
        writer.SaveToFile(fileToCreate);
    }
```

I am looking for a way to create a table in word document with populated data from above XML document.

Comment: would any one please suggest any idea or any other way to achieve this solution

Comment: Did you share precisely the XML that you are trying to insert into the custom XML part? What you posted is malformed, because the opening `<Genre>` tag is missing. Further, can you elaborate on what you are trying to achieve? You are merely creating a custom XML part into which you insert some XML. How does that relate to your question about how to create a table?

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow i modified my question , hope it will be clear now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you likely want is an Open XML `Table` (`w:tbl` element) like the following:

```xml
<w:tbl xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Name</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Released</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Crash</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>2005</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>The Departed</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>2006</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>The Pursuit of Happiness</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>2006</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>The Bucket List</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>2007</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
</w:tbl>
```

The above `w:tbl` is created from your XML by the following `CanCreateTableFromXml` unit test, which simply calls the `TransformMovies(XElement)` pure functional transformation method. The latter creates a header row based on the first movie and one content row for each movie.

```cs
        private const string MoviesXml =
            @"<?xml version=""1.0"" encoding=""UTF-8""?>
<Movies>
  <Movie>
    <Name>Crash</Name>
    <Released>2005</Released>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>The Departed</Name>
    <Released>2006</Released>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>The Pursuit of Happiness</Name>
    <Released>2006</Released>
  </Movie>
  <Movie>
    <Name>The Bucket List</Name>
    <Released>2007</Released>
  </Movie>
</Movies>";

        private static Table TransformMovies(XElement movies)
        {
            var headerRow = new[]
            {
                new TableRow(movies
                    .Elements()
                    .First()
                    .Elements()
                    .Select(e => new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(e.Name.LocalName))))))
            };
            var movieRows = movies.Elements().Select(TransformMovie);

            return new Table(headerRow.Concat(movieRows));
        }

        private static OpenXmlElement TransformMovie(XElement element)
        {
            return element.Name.LocalName switch
            {
                "Movie" => new TableRow(element.Elements().Select(TransformMovie)),
                _ => new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(element.Value)))),
            };
        }

        [Fact]
        public void CanCreateTableFromXml()
        {
            var movies = XElement.Parse(MoviesXml);
            var table = TransformMovies(movies);
        }
```

#### Update on 2019-12-29: How to Call TransformMovies

The following example shows how you can call the `TransformMovies` method in your `InsertTable` method.

```cs
        private void InsertTable(WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument)
        {
            const string xmlFile = @"Resources\Movies.xml";
            MainDocumentPart mainPart = wordprocessingDocument.MainDocumentPart;

            // How to read the XML and create a table in word document filled 
            // with data from XML

            // First, read the Movies XML string from your XML file.
            string moviesXml = File.ReadAllText(xmlFile);

            // Second, create the table as previously shown in the unit test method.
            XElement movies = XElement.Parse(moviesXml);
            Table table = TransformMovies(movies);

            // Third, append the Table to your empty Body.
            mainPart.Document.Body.AppendChild(table);
        }
```

#### Update on 2019-12-30: How to Add Table Borders

Looking at your changed `TransformMovies` method in which you are trying to add table borders, this method produces the following Open XML table markup:

```xml
<w:tbl xmlns:w="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/wordprocessingml/2006/main">
  <w:tr>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Name</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
    <w:tc>
      <w:p>
        <w:r>
          <w:t>Released</w:t>
        </w:r>
      </w:p>
    </w:tc>
  </w:tr>
  <w:tblPr>
    <w:tblBorders>
      <w:top w:val="single" w:sz="24" />
      <w:bottom w:val="single" w:sz="24" />
      <w:left w:val="single" w:sz="24" />
      <w:right w:val="single" w:sz="24" />
      <w:insideH w:val="single" w:sz="24" />
      <w:insideV w:val="single" w:sz="24" />
    </w:tblBorders>
  </w:tblPr>
</w:tbl>
```

We can only see the header row while the movie rows are missing. The `w:tblPr` element (`TableProperties` instance) is added as the last child element of `w:tbl` (`Table`).

Why are you not able to render the data (or why are those movie rows missing)? You are not adding the `movieRows` to the `headerRow` in your changed `TransformMovies` method. `Concat` is a pure method that does not mutate `headerRow`. It only returns a concatenated sequence but does not change the first sequence (`headerRow` in this case).

Why are you not able to add border lines to the table? You are adding the `TableProperties` as the last child element of the `Table`. However, as per the Open XML standard, it must be the first one. While Microsoft Word often tolerates invalid Open XML markup, it does not do that in this case.

The following excerpt from your changed `TransformedMovies` method points out the mistakes that lead to those issues:

```cs
Table table = new Table();

var headerRow = new[]
{
    new TableRow(movies
        .Elements()
        .First()
        .Elements()
        .Select(e => new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(e.Name.LocalName))))))
};
var movieRows = movies.Elements().Select(TransformMovie);

// The following line of code is the first culprit.
// The return value of the pure method is not used (Visual Studio should show a warning).
// The headerRow array is unchanged.
headerRow.Concat(movieRows);

TableProperties tblProp = ...

// At this point, you append the unchanged header row.
table.Append(headerRow);

// The following line of code is the second culprit.
// tblProp is appended as the last child of table. It must be the first one.
table.AppendChild(tblProp);
```

You should rewrite your method as follows to make it work:

```cs
private static Table TransformMovies(XElement movies)
{
    var table = new Table();

    var tblPr = new TableProperties(
        new TableBorders(
            new TopBorder { Val = BorderValues.Single, Size = 24 },
            new BottomBorder { Val = BorderValues.Single, Size = 24 },
            new LeftBorder { Val = BorderValues.Single, Size = 24 },
            new RightBorder { Val = BorderValues.Single, Size = 24 },
            new InsideHorizontalBorder { Val = BorderValues.Single, Size = 24 },
            new InsideVerticalBorder { Val = BorderValues.Single, Size = 24 }));

    var headerRow = new TableRow(movies
        .Elements()
        .First()
        .Elements()
        .Select(e => new TableCell(new Paragraph(new Run(new Text(e.Name.LocalName))))));

    IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> movieRows = movies.Elements().Select(TransformMovie);

    // Append child elements in the right order.
    table.AppendChild(tblPr);
    table.AppendChild(headerRow);
    table.Append(movieRows);

    return table;
}
```

Note that I created a `headerRow` array in my earlier answer to then use `headerRow.Concat(movieRows)` in the following return statement:

```cs
// Return Table with IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> added to it.
return new Table(headerRow.Concat(movieRows));
```

I did this because I like a functional approach to programming but, unfortunately, the constructors of the strongly typed classes provided by the Open XML SDK don't let you mix individual `OpenXmlElement` and `IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement>` instances as required in the following return statement (which does *not* work, mind you):

```cs
// Return Table with OpenXmlElement and IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement> added to it.
return new Table(headerRow, movieRows);
```

Now, if you have to add multiple individual instances (i.e., `TableProperties`, `TableRow`) and a collection (i.e., `IEnumerable<OpenXmlElement>`), you can as well use the `AppendChild` (for individual instances) and `Append` (for collections) methods. In this case, you don't need to create arrays or lists for individual instances to concatenate those and pass them to the constructor in one go.

Comment: many thanks for quick response , how can i call `transformMovies` method in this method `InsertTable(WordprocessingDocument wordprocessingDocument)`

Comment: @EnigmaState, please have a look at my updated answer. Please mark as the answer and upvote if this is helpful.

Comment: many thanks , one last query i would like to add table border as well .. with the above table i am getting table without borders .. Could you please help me on this..

Comment: I also updated my code to reflect your changes.. thanks

Comment: @EnigmaState, please have a look at my update. I added this to my original answer but it might have been better to ask a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative approach that uses [GemBox.Document](https://www.nuget.org/packages/GemBox.Document/), it can simplify DOCX file's processing (creation, editing, printing, converting, etc...):

```
string xmlFile = @"C:\wordDoc\movies.xml";
string docxFile = @"C:\wordDoc\test.docx";

var document = new DocumentModel();

var section = new Section(document);
document.Sections.Add(section);

var table = new Table(document);
section.Blocks.Add(table);

foreach (var xmlRow in XDocument.Load(xmlFile).Descendants("Movie"))
    table.Rows.Add(
        new TableRow(document,
            new TableCell(document,
                new Paragraph(document, xmlRow.Element("Name").Value)),
            new TableCell(document,
                new Paragraph(document, xmlRow.Element("Released").Value))));

table.TableFormat.Borders.SetBorders(MultipleBorderTypes.All, BorderStyle.Double, Color.Red, 2);

document.Save(docxFile);
```

Here is how the resulting "test.docx" file looks like:

[image]

Also, you can easily add those list items from "fruitList".
For instance, see [Lists](https://www.gemboxsoftware.com/document/examples/word-lists/603) example.

Comment: Just note that GemBox.Document is a commercial product the free version of which is limited to 20 paragraphs (meaning one header row and 9 movies in this example). It might still be interesting for those who want to abstract away some of the complexities of using the very low-level Open XML SDK. In that case, you should also look at other commercial products such as Aspose.Words, for example.

Comment: @ThomasBarnekow yes, GemBox.Document has free and pro version and unfortunately in case of a table element the free version limitation can be easily exceeded because each cell contains at least one paragraph. Regarding Aspose, when I was researching the available solutions I did find it as well, but it's extremely expensive, especially if you need to deploy it somewhere like on a server…